# Append CSV using Comparisons of CSV Files

Tags: csv, powershell, comparison-operators

I am trying to enter data into one csv using a comparison of the two csvs. The data is a result of the comparison between the two csvs.

For Example:

CSV 1 says

```
Host,Type
Host1,Server
Host2,Switch
Host3,Hub
Host4,Router
```

CSV 2 says:

```
List of Types, Hosts
              ,Host1 random letters Host2
              ,random letters Host3 Host2
              ,Host4 Host3 Host2
```

The output should be

```
List of Types,Hosts
server switch,Host1 random letters Host2
hub switch,random letters Host3 Host2
router hub switch,Host4 Host3 Host2
```

This is what I have:

My problem seems to be the comparison part

```
  $CSV1 = Import-Csv "Pathname1.csv"

Foreach ($title in $CSV1)
{
    $Hosts =$title."Hosts"
    $Type=$title."Type"
}

$csv2 = Import-Csv "Pathname2.csv"

foreach($title in $CSV2)
{
    $Typelist = $title."List of Types"
    $Hostlist = $title."Hosts"

    if ($Hostlist -contains $Hosts)
    {
    $title.'List of Types'= $Type
    }
 }

 $csv2 | export-csv "export.csv"
```

which outputs absolutely nothing except for what was originally there.

Comment: What kind of output are you getting? This often has the clue as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: Nothing shows up under `List of Types`. However if I do a `$title.'List of Types'="This is blank"`... with out the `IF` statement...All of the lines will say `This is blank`

Comment: why are $csv1 and $csv2 importing the same file?  also, is your contents of csv2 in  your question formatted exactly how the rows and columns are in  your file (aka, no type)?

Comment: I changed the filenames to be different. I am using 2 different csv's. Im not sure I understand your last question but my files does look like that...so it has random strings in between the host names

Comment: Should you not have a ' ; ' at the end of each function declaration, or is this script driven by indentation?

Comment: I've never had to use a ' ; '. Should I? The indentation is just to make the code look cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv files really do not make much sense to me in how they are organized, but that does not mean your problem cannot be solved with some thought and learning how to break your problem down and step through the debugger to get it working.

I have whipped up some code to give the desired output, and even added a few lines of potentially helpful debug statements (output) that can be uncommented to see progress.

**CSV1**

```
Host,Type
Host1,Server
Host2,Switch
Host3,Hub
Host4,Router
```

**CSV2**

```
List of Types,Hosts
,Host1 random1 letters1 Host2
,random2 letters2 Host3 Host2
,Host4 Host3 Host2
```

**Code**

```
"-=-=-=-=-=-=-= start"

$content1 = Get-Content d:\junk\c1.csv
$data1 = $content1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @('Host','Type')
"c1===="
$content1
"csv1===="
$data1 | ft

$content2 = Get-Content d:\junk\c2.csv
$data2 = $content2 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @('Type','Hosts')
"c2===="
$content2
"csv2===="
$data2 | ft

#"data===="
$output = @()
foreach ($hostList in ($data2.Hosts | select -Skip 1)){
    # don't use variable name $host. it is a reserved variable.
    # see about_Automatic_Variables
    # https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx
    $subHosts = $hostList -split ' '

    #"subhosts===="
    #$subHosts

    $types = @()
    foreach ($subHost in $subHosts)
    {
        #$("sh = $subHost")
        $typeMatch = (($data1 | select -Skip 1) | where {$_.Host -eq $subHost}).Type

        if ($typeMatch)
        {
            $types += $typeMatch
        }
    }
    $types = $types -join ' '

    #"types===="
    #$types

    $matches = @{}
    $matches.Add($types, $hostList)
    $output += $matches
}

"final list===="
$output

"-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- end"
```

**Output**

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-= start
c1====
Host,Type
Host1,Server
Host2,Switch
Host3,Hub
Host4,Router
csv1====

Host  Type  
----  ----  
Host  Type  
Host1 Server
Host2 Switch
Host3 Hub   
Host4 Router

c2====
List of Types,Hosts
,Host1 random1 letters1 Host2
,random2 letters2 Host3 Host2
,Host4 Host3 Host2
csv2====

Type          Hosts                       
----          -----                       
List of Types Hosts                       
              Host1 random1 letters1 Host2
              random2 letters2 Host3 Host2
              Host4 Host3 Host2           

final list====

Name              Value                       
----              -----                       
Server Switch     Host1 random1 letters1 Host2
Hub Switch        random2 letters2 Host3 Host2
Router Hub Switch Host4 Host3 Host2           
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- end
```

Comment: That is an excellent answer and explanation however, it is not working with my actual data. The difference in the two is that I have spaces in between my Host and the number.
How can I match lets say `Host 2` and `Switch` in CSV1 if I had the word `Host 2` in CSV 2 under Hosts.

Comment: The issue is that you are using items like "Host1 random letters Host2" for your hosts, which implies space as a delimiter.  You cannot then try to use that delimiter in an item, unless you put it in quotes or something like that ('Host1' 'random' 'letters' 'Host2') for example.  I am not sure how you are getting this data, what you intend to do with it, but there is probably a better way.  Suggest you do some research on best practices (data structure, design patterns, working sample code) for whatever your project is calling for.